# the number of ways in which 135 can be written as sum of ' $n$ ' natural numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathrm{N}$ denote the number of ways in which 135 can be written as sum of ' $n$ ' natural numbers in the following manner.
$$
135=a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots . .+a_n(n \in N)
$$
The digits $1,2,3 \ldots . .9$ are used to form numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots \ldots ., a_n$ such that all the digits are used and each digit is used exactly once in the sum. For example $135=\frac{18+95+2+3+4+6+7}{\text { Each digit from } 1-9 \text { is used once }}$

So far I got this

None of $a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots . .+a_n$ can be a 3-digit numbers
Hence, a few of them are 2-digit numbers, and rest are 1-digit numbers
Let sum of digits in terms in the place $=\mathrm{k}$. Then sum of units place $=45-\mathrm{k}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \therefore 135=10 \times \mathrm{k}+45-\mathrm{k} \Rightarrow 9 \mathrm{k}=135-45=90 \Rightarrow \mathrm{k}=10 \\
& \mathrm{k}=1+9=2+8=3+7=4+6 \rightarrow 4 \times{ }^7 \mathrm{P}_2 \times 7 ! \\
& \mathrm{k}=1+2+7=1+3+6=1+4+5=2+3+5 \rightarrow 4 \times{ }^6 \mathrm{P}_3 \times 6 ! \\
& \mathrm{k}=1+2+3+4 \rightarrow 1 \times{ }^5 \mathrm{P}_4 \times 5 ! \\
& \therefore \text { Total }=4 \times 7 \times 6 \times 7 !+4 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 6 !+5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 5 ! \\
& =21 \times 8 !+500 \times 6 ! \\
& =1676 \times 6 !
\end{aligned}
$$
But I believe this is wrong. Can someody confirm or give an other solution.

Comment: Do your *natural numbers* include $0$? Is the digit $0$ allowed as a digit in your permitted $a_i$?

Comment: no they are only natural numbers so no '0'

Comment: This might get closed as its very specific. You could try "brute forcing" it with a computer with a recursive relation like `N(135, {1..9}) = N(134, {2..9}) + N(134, {1,3,4,...9}) + ...` and so on. The part I've partly written is just for `1 + (something)`, so there are going to be a lot of terms on the right side of the recursion, 2^8 for each digit, plus then you look at things like `12+`. It's possible the recursion would get too big, though